# R Imputation With MICE

Tags: r, data.table, r-mice

```
set.seed(1)
    library(data.table)
    data=data.table(STUDENT = 1:1000,
                    OUTCOME = sample(20:90, r = T),
                    X1 = runif(1000),
                    X2 = runif(1000),
                    X3 = runif(1000))
    data[, X1 := fifelse(X1 > .9, NA_real_, X1)]
    data[, X2 := fifelse(X2 > .78 & X2 < .9, NA_real_, X1)]
    data[, X3 := fifelse(X3 < .1, NA_real_, X1)]
```

Say you have data as shown and you wish to impute values for X1, X2, X3 and leave out STUDENT and OUTCOME for the imputation processing.

I can do

```
library(mice)
dataIMPUTE=mice(data[, c("X1", "X2", "X3")], m = 1)
```

but how do I get together the imputing values from dataIMPUTE with STUDENT and OUTCOME? I am afraid that I will merge wrong and that is why I ask if you have advice for this.

Comment: Can you change your example.  I get an error `mice(data[, .(X1, X2, X3)], m = 1)#
Error in edit.setup(data, setup, ...) : 
  `mice` detected constant and/or collinear variables.`

Comment: @akrun all updated now thanks a bunch

Comment: For some reason, I get error `mice(data[, c("X1", "X2", "X3")], m = 1)#
Error in edit.setup(data, setup, ...) : mice` detected constant and/or collinear variables. No predictors were left after their removal.`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the complete data set in the imputation, but change the `predictorMatrix` so that `STUDENT` and `OUTCOME` are not used in the imputation model.

First, you need to run `mice` to extract the `predictorMatrix` (without calculating the imputation). Then you can set all columns to 0 that shouldn't be included in the imputation model. However, all your variables are still contained in your `dataIMPUTE` object:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
data=data.table(STUDENT = 1:1000,
                OUTCOME = sample(20:90, r = T),
                X1 = runif(1000),
                X2 = runif(1000),
                X3 = runif(1000))
index_1 <- sample(1:1000, 100)
index_2 <- sample(1:1000, 100)
index_3 <- sample(1:1000, 100)
data[index_1, X1 := NA_real_]
data[index_2, X2 := NA_real_]
data[index_3, X3 := NA_real_]

library(mice)
init <- mice(data, maxit = 0, print = FALSE)

# extract the predictor matrix
pred_mat <- init$predictorMatrix

# remove STUDENT and OUTCOME as predictors
pred_mat[, c("STUDENT", "OUTCOME")] <- 0

# do the imputation
dataIMPUTE = mice(data, pred = pred_mat, m = 1)
```